# When Developing the database then compolsury to define the primary key or forign key in each tables of the database?

Tags: database, relational-database

When Developing the database then compolsury to  define the primary key or forign key in each tables of the databse if any tables that do not contain any unique field that time how can we connect the table with other table.
Suppose i have three tabe.

table1 Personel Detail

```
Emai_Address (PK)
Name
City
ContactNo
Land_Line_No
D_O_B
Gender
Marital_Status
Language_Known
```

Table2 Professiona_Detail

```
Total_Experiance
Annual_Salary
Functional_Area
Current_Industry
Key_Skill
Resume_HeadLine
```

Table3 WorkPreference

```
Specify Your Preference
Start Working
Prefered Location
Job Type
```

The Obove Table1 contain the PK but Table2 or Table 3 does not contain any Pk Or FK then  how can connect this three table.

Comment: What's wrong with your `l` key?

Comment: You have not explained what the three tables represent.  Does "professional_detail" apply to the people listed in "personal_detail"?  Or does it represent (for instance) requirements of a job that is being posted?  Same for "work_preference".

Answer (score 2):

No. It's not compulsory. But **HIGHLY** recommended!

Some SQL guru once said:

> *If it doesn't have a primary key, it's not a table!*

Live by that statement!

And foreign keys will make your database more secure, and avoid "zombie" rows. Again: it's not compulsory or technically necessary by all means, but you'll get yourself into trouble if you don't know it right from the start! Trust me.... been there, cleaned up that mess......

Comment: Couldn't disagree more about defining PK's and FK's (think shadow-audit table). But that doesn't mean your answer is wrong.

Comment: @Stephanie.  What exactly are you disagreeing with (think: relational-database question, as tagged; not shadow-audit question) ?

Answer (score 2):

`Table2` and `Table3` should have a `FK` to `Table1`. Otherwise you will not know what person the records in those tables are for. Each table should also have a `PK` defined for it. This is so that you can uniquely identify a row when doing `UPDATES` or `DELETES`.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that will enforce primary/foreign keys apart from you as a developer.

They are not *compulsary*, but are best practice and *should* be created.

Answer (score 1):

*When <strike>Developing</strike> modelling the database then compolsury to define the primary key or forign key in each tables of the databse if any tables that do not contain any unique field that time how can we connect the table with other table.*

(1) Yes.

You are experiencing complications and difficulties at step 6 because you have not completed step 5.  The steps have to be followed in sequence.

A Relational Database requires that the rows (not the identity column) in each table are unique.  It is compulsory.  If the rows are not unique, it is not a Relational table, it is something else, a bucket of fish.

After that FKs, etc will be easy.  before that, FKs etc will be impossible.

(2) You already have a very good, stable unique Identifier for `Person`.  The `Professional` and `WorkPreference` tables are missing a column or two.  They do not sit out their on their own.  Who or what does `Professional` and `WorkPreference` apply to ?

They belong to a `Person`.  The only `Person` Identifier you have so far is `EmailAddress`.  So `EmailAddress` needs to be added to `Professional` and `WorkPreference`.

`EmailAddress` is the PK in `Professional` and `WorkPreference`.

`EmailAddress` is also the FK in `Professional` and `WorkPreference` to `Person`.  (So far the cardinality is 1::1.)

(3)  Now you may also need an Unique Constraint on `Person.Name`, but then you have to deal with two "Bob Smith" and "Bob Smith" vs "Smith, Bob" vs "Robert Smith".  So there is still some work to do there.  If it is a simple database it may not matter `Person.Name` may be good enough.

That is it, the task is complete at the logical level.

(4)  Now at the physical level (elements that the user does not see), you may decide that carrying the CHAR(30) `EmailAddress` in the child tables is not sensible for performance reasons, so you may **add** a narrow Surrogate Key to `Person`, such as `PersonId INT`.  **A Surrogate Key is always an additional column and index**; it is not a substitution for the natural keys; you still need `EmailAddress UNIQUE` as the natural key that maintains uniqueness of rows.

Then you can use `PersonId` as the PK in `Person`.

Then you migrate `PersonId` as the FK and PK to `Professional` and `WorkPreference`; *instead of* `EmailAddress`.

But you cannot give up `Person.EmailAddress UNIQUE`, because that is the basis of maintaining unique rows in `Person`.